# Is there a way to get Blue-Proximity working or an alternative?

Tags: package-management, bluetooth, python-2.7

I'm looking for a way to use my mobile to automatically unlock my laptop. [Blue Proximity](https://sourceforge.net/projects/blueproximity/) seemed like a good answer, but it's clearly been abandoned as a project and I'm having problems with some of the dependencies. Has anyone got this working on 20.04 or got an alternative? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I forked the project and upgraded it. Now it runs on Python 3 so it will work on Ubuntu 20.04.
Find it here:

https://github.com/tiktaalik-dev/blueproximity

I haven't created .deb packages though because I don't know how (yet), but it can run directly from a folder in your user directory. Just create a link to the .sh file in that folder.

Hope you find it as useful as the old one :-)

Cheers.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I haven't had time to try it yet, but as soon as I do I'll reply again. :-)